# facebook comment count wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook comments on my drupal site. I'm using the below code from the facebook developer site to display how many comments an article has:

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count>
```

The problem is it's showing the wrong number. I have an article that shows as having 2 comments when there are none. This particular article had some test comments which have since been deleted. These comments do not appear in the moderation panel either.
Even the graph api shows the article as having 2 comments.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You may use FQL link_stats for geting the comment count.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='http://example.com/'
```